# Подскажите плагин на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Что-то вроде карусельки (не знаю, как точно сформулиривовать), в которой будет выводится три блока с контентом, а при нажатии на кнопку влево будет появляться еще один блок, а первый исчезать. Что-то вроде этого слайдера товаров на главной
http://elegantthemes.com/preview/eStore/?paged=2

Answer (score 2):

Конкретный слайдер не могу сказать, может, найдете [тут](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=slider&sort=)?

Comment: Спасибо, просмотрю там.